# OpenJDK 16 shows as 17 on MacOS Apple Silicon when installed with Homebrew

Tags: java, homebrew, apple-silicon

Wanted to install openjdk 16 on MacOS (macOS Big Sur 11.0.1; Apple M1). All went well but the versions showing aren't matching. Shows **OpenJDK 17** but the path is **/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.1/**. Not sure if I have openjdk 16 or 17?

Steps:

```
1. $brew update
2. $brew install openjdk
```

But `$java -version` shows as 17

```
$ java -version
  openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17+0)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17+0, mixed mode)

OR

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
  17 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 17"
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
       /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The confusing part is `brew info openjdk` shows:
**This is a beta version of openjdk for Apple Silicon (openjdk 17 preview).**

```
$ brew info openjdk
openjdk: stable 16.0.1 (bottled) [keg-only]
Development kit for the Java programming language https://openjdk.java.net/ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.1 (618 files, 281.4MB)
Poured from bottle on 2021-05-31 at 23:05:51
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openjdk.rb License: GPL-2.0-only with Classpath-exception-2.0
...
This is a beta version of openjdk for Apple Silicon (openjdk 17 preview).
...
```

On digging more, part of the code for the [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk) formula **openjdk** at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openjdk.rb is actually installing 17 but showing the version as 16.0.1 on purpose?

```
if Hardware::CPU.arm?   
  # Temporarily use a openjdk 17 preview on Apple Silicon   
  # (because it is better than nothing)    
  url "https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/archive/refs/tags/jdk-17+24.tar.gz"    
  sha256 "9d1ea3fc63ce860e55a9be77f670b18fa7b7e5c9773dca3c70042403e1ee285c"   
  version "16.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-posting the answer from discussion in Github with Homebrew.

Ref: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1594#discussioncomment-816728

When you use command `brew info openjdk` , i.e., a non-versioned formula in brew will always be the latest version available from upstream. In this case that is 17 for ARM (as a preview) and 16 on x86.

```
$brew info openjdk
openjdk: stable 16.0.1 (bottled) [keg-only]
Development kit for the Java programming language
https://openjdk.java.net/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.1 (618 files, 281.4MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2021-05-31 at 23:05:51
```

On M1/ARM it actually installs version 17 but folders would be named as "16". Yes, this may be an issue, but this is how, brew is, as of now (June 2021).